# How to navigate without cursors in a connection

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql-js

I have an array/table with lets say 10000 items.

Now I try to show the items from index 4000 to 4010 in my react relay client.

But at the moment the `connectionArgs` only allow navigation with `cursors`, but I DON'T want to page until I arrive at item 4000.

How to I navigate to a given offset with a GraphQL query ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use `this.props.relay.setVariable` to pass a variable value to the server side by declaring the variable in your Relay.Container fragment, and server GraphQL schema.

The example code is below. Pay particular attention to the parts marked with **NOTE:**

On your client-side:

```
// Your React component 
class ItemList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { startItemIndex: 0 };
  }

  nextPage() {
    const _nextPageItemIndex = this.state.startItemIndex + itemCountOnPage;
    // NOTE: Call this.props.relay.setVariables to force re-fetch 
    this.props.relay.setVariables({ startItemIndex: _nextPageItemIndex });
    this.setState({ startItemIndex: _nextPageItemIndex });
  }
  ...
}

// Your Relay data declaration
Relay.createContainer(ItemList, {
  initialVariables: {
    itemStartIndex:  0,
  },
  fragments: {
    itemList: () => Relay.QL`
      // NOTE: Declare your variable in the GraphQL fragment
      fragment on ItemList(itemStartIndex: $itemStartIndex) {
        id,
        listName,
        items,
        ...
      }
    `
  }
}
```

On your server-side, in your GraphQL schema:

```
var ItemListType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'ItemList',
  fields: () => ({
    listName: {type: GraphQLString},
    items: ...
  }),
});

// App is what your Route will query, and it holds your itemList
// Relay.QL`
//   query GameQuery {
//     itemList
//   }
// `
var AppType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'App',
  fields: () => ({
    itemList: {
      // NOTE: This is where your variables will appear
      args: {
        itemStartIndex: {type: GraphQLInt},
      },
      type: new GraphQLList(ItemListType),
      ...
      resolve: (appObj, args) => {
        // NOTE: Use args.itemStartIndex to pull out your list
      }
    },
  }),
})
```

- For tutorial reference: https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-containers.html#content
- For working code reference (see 'A Simple Parameterization (High Scores example)): https://facebook.github.io/relay/